# How to create generic CSS class with input parameter

Tags: html, css, less

I am showing list of items on UI. Those items have attribute as tLevel. Depending on tLevel value I want to create tree structure.

Something like this

```
item1                   tLevel=0
    item2               tLevel=1
        item3           tLevel=2    
    item4               tLevel=1
        item5           tLevel=2
            item6       tLevel=3    
            item7       tLevel=3
            item8       tLevel=3
item9                   tLevel=0
    item10              tLevel=1
    item11              tLevel=1
```

HTML template

```
<div class="treeLevelCSS(' + tLevel + ')" />
```

CSS should be something like

```
.treeLevelCSS(tLevel){
    "margin-left: " + (tLevel * 15) + "px"
}
```

I am not sure what I have written above in HTML and CSS is right, but just to give an idea of what I want to achieve here.

Comment: Look for css pre-processors. [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) might help you on that

Comment: So... you mentioned [less]. Have you tried anything so far yet? (the code for above snippet in either CSS preprocessor is trivial, so it's only a matter of you to read corresponding documentation).

Comment: I am using LESS, but I know basics . Don't have any idea about SASS.
Is it possible with LESS to achieve this?

Comment: See my answer below. Just realize that since you can't generate CSS *dynamically* from within HTML (CSS classes are not functions and can't have any "arguments" like `.treeLevelCSS(3)`). What you need in this case is to simply generate a predefined number of such classes (i.e. `.treeLevelCSS0`, `.treeLevelCSS1` etc . - considering you don't need an infinite number of tree levels, this should be fine). If you're looking for *true dynamic* styles generations then it's not a CSS thing (and thus neither CSS preprocessor can help) and a scripting is your only choice.

Comment: (All above is of course if you don't want the solution offered by @MerlinMason. Personally I'd recommend the same in the first place).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Less, what you need in a simplest case is a [mixin](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature) and [selector "interpolation"](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-selectors), e.g.:

```
.treeLevel(0);
.treeLevel(1);
.treeLevel(2);
.treeLevel(3);

.treeLevel(@level) {
    .treeLevelCSS@{level} {
        margin-left: @level * 15px;
    }
}
```

Then, depending on your needs, get it further improved with other stuff. For example using loops to reduce repetition and/or possibility to generate an arbitrary number of class. See native Less [loops](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature) and/or a syntactic sugar goodies for those like [`.for`](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less.curious/blob/master/articles/generic-for.md):

```
@import "for";

.tree-level- {
    // generate 8 level classes:
    .for(0, 7); .-each(@i) {
        &@{i} {
            margin-left: 15px * @i;
        }
    }
}
```

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/domgQm?editors=110) for above (slightly modified) snippet.

Comment: This is working as expected, but the import statement is throwing error when I did "lessc TreeLevel.less" from location where this less file is located.
ERROR : FileError: 'for.less' wasn't found.

Does this import needed? becasue in Codepen Demo I removed it and it still works, but on my machine if I remove it error is shown for '.for' statement

Comment: Need to add '@import "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/seven-phases-max/less.curious/master/src/for";'   in my less file. This is not good though **Dynamic import**

Comment: @ifOnly, just download the file and use it just like any other ordinary Less library/module. The one at GitHub should be used ***only*** for Codepen (or other online playgrounds) demos.

Comment: Yes. Copied for.less and now its working as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If possible it might be beneficial to use nested  lists here, with each level just having padding applied to it.

For example:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>1</li>
</ul>
```

and...

```
li {
  list-style:none;
}
ul ul {
  padding-left:20px;
}
```

Should do the job, demo: http://codepen.io/merlinmason/pen/vORaVB

Comment: I want to use tLevel value to determine spaces I want to keep. e.g. tLevel =0 means 4 spaces and tlevel=1 means 8 spaces like that.